# Crud functionality, Trying to update user details with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php and I have a login system and an account which allows users to edit their details however when they fill in the form the database does not update and my error message does not show? Can anyone help?

accountamend.php

```
 <?php
 include 'connection.php'; // this includes my connection to the database
$ID=$_GET['ID'];
$query="SELECT ID, email, password, FROM users WHERE ID=$ID";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die (mysqli_error($connection));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
} else {
$row=NULL;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Update Details </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homecss.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700' rel='stylesheet'       type='text/css'>
 </head>
 <body>
<form method ="post" action="amendaccount.php">
    <fieldsetclass="fieldset-width">
 <legend>
Enter New Details
</legend>
<input type="hidden" name"ID" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" />
<label for="email">Email: </label>
<input type = "text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" />
<br/>
<label for ="password"> Password: </label>
<input type = "password" name="password" value="<?php echo $row['password']; ?>" />
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
<input type="reset" value="clear" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

editaccount.php

```
 <?php
include 'connection.php';
$ID=$_POST['ID'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$query="UPDATE users SET email='$email', password='$password' WHERE ID='$ID'";
mysqli_query($connection,$query);
 echo "Update Success";
 ?>
```

Comment: `<form method ="post" action="amendaccount.php">` .. where is your action page to which the data will be posted?

Comment: my amendaccount.php is my editaccount.php i just renamed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an error in your code here:

```
<input type="hidden" name"ID" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $ID; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in your editaccount.php you could add something like

```
printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
```

after your mysqli_query statement so you could see the latest error (if any).

Did you output your $query and try to execute it by hand? Maybe this shows you an error as well?

Comment: I did the error I am getting is: Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\ISD\ISD WEBSITE\accountamend.php on line 3
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM users WHERE ID=''' at line 1

Comment: and on my edit account which is named amendaccount.php is 
Notice: Undefined index: ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\ISD\ISD WEBSITE\amendaccount.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\ISD\ISD WEBSITE\amendaccount.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\ISD\ISD WEBSITE\amendaccount.php on line 5
UPDATE users SET email='', password='' WHERE ID=''Errormessage:

Comment: so you are missing some data that you need to build your query... make sure you have those and everything should be fine.